# Avoid v-deep duplication with SCSS and Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3, vue-loader, vue-sfc

Vue 3 deprecated using `v-deep` as a combinator: https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0023-scoped-styles-changes.md

We have existing code using SCSS and `v-deep` like this:

```
.class ::v-deep {
  .child-class1 {...}
  .child-class2 {...}
}
```

Which compiles into something like this:

```css
.class[data-xxxxxx] .child-class1 {...}
.class[data-xxxxxx] .child-class2 {...}
```

In Vue 3, this syntax is deprecated, and we need to do this instead:

```
.class {
  ::v-deep(.child-class1) {...}
  ::v-deep(.child-class2) {...}
}
```

We have to repeat `v-deep` for every nested rule. In reality, there are many more, and some complicated rules.

Is there any way, in SCSS to construct a nested block where all the inner rules are wrapped into this `::v-deep(...)` syntax?

---

I'm looking for something like this (not actual syntax):

```
::v-deep(&) {
  .child-class1 {...}
  .child-class2 {...}
}
```

Except that the self-selector (`&`) would have kind of the opposite meaning, referencing the child selector instead of the parent.

Answer (score 6):

You can do pretty much the same thing with an empty selector argument:

```
.class ::v-deep() {
  .child-class1 {...}
  .child-class2 {...}
}
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't that just the same as `.class ::v-deep() .child-class`. I have tried it, and it actually works, but I fear that it works for the same reason that the deprecated `class ::v-deep .child-class` combinator syntax works, and it will not work when the deprecated functionality is removed.

Comment: No, it's not the same or there would be a deprecation warning as when using the old syntax. It works because it uses the new syntax.

Comment: This syntax does not works with `less`: it throws "Missing closing ')'". As a current workaround, I'm using `.class ::v-deep(*)` but it does not get the exact same result.